# Block-level elements not fully expanded inside x-scrollable DIV

Tags: html, css, scroll, width

I have this code in HTML:

```
<code class="codecontainer">
<pre>
<span class="lna">Line 1! This line is very long and goes beyond the container limits, so the content is scrolled horizontally...</span>
<span class="lnb">Line 2!</span>
<span class="lna">Line 3!</span>
<span class="lnb">Line 4!</span>
</pre>
</code>
```

And then some styles that applies to it:

```
code.codecontainer {
 display: block;
 overflow: auto;
 background: #fff;
}

code.codecontainer .ln1 {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
 background: #f2f2f2;
}

code.codecontainer .ln2 {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
 background: #f6f6f6;
}
```

The problem is that when I resize the screen width (to test for mobile support) the lines (".lna" and ".lnb") have a width equal to their parent (".codecontainer"), which is somehow logical. But when I scroll the bar of the parent element, I can see its background (white) in the part that was hidden before the scrolling. I don't know how to make ".lna" and ".lnb" to take the width of the whole space, including the part revealed with the scrollbar.

I hope I didn't mess everyone up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you want to consider **`jQuery`** or  just **`javascript`** to solve the issue.

First, get the scroll width that is caused by the overflow on the `codecontainer`.
Then set the width of the elements inside the `codecontainer` (which in this case are `.lnb` and `.lna`) to the scroll width.

Something like this (**jQuery**):

```
var overflowWidth = document.getElementById('codecontainer').scrollWidth;
$('.lnb').width(overflowWidth);
$('.lna').width(overflowWidth);
```

**[SAMPLE in jsFiddle - jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/PAXdp/2/)**

or

Something like this (**pure javascript**):

```
var overflowWidth = document.getElementById('codecontainer').scrollWidth;
var lines = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
lines[i].style.width = overflowWidth +"px";
}
```

**[SAMPLE in jsFiddle - javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/PAXdp/4/)**

Comment: As I forsee there won't be a pure HTML/CSS solution, this is a good palliative. Meanwhile, I'll wait and see if someone else finds the holy grial. Thank you!